# Parse random String & return Value (JSON)

Tags: json, parsing

Edit: It works pretty well now and this makes it possible to reference URLs in a JSON file and return their related pairs (e.g game name / year / image url). Here's the code.

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('jfetch', {
  schema: {},
  init: function () {
    var url = 'json/text.json';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( 'GET', url, true );
    request.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

      var jsongames = JSON.parse( event.target.response )
      var keys = Object.keys(jsongames);
      var random = jsongames[keys.length * Math.random() << 0];
      var games = random.Title + ' (' + random.Developer + ')'
      var textEntity = document.querySelector('#text');
      textEntity.setAttribute("value", games)          
      var gurl = random.Imageurl
      var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
      sceneEl.querySelector('a-box').setAttribute('material', {src:gurl}); 

    } );
    request.send( null );
  }
});
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

---

Original Question: I would like to fetch a random "Title" string in my Json file and return its corresponding value. I know the simple [test](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-json-to-text?path=README.md:1:0) code works but I have no idea how to apply it to an array with lots of objects and to add the random parsing element. Can someone please help me with a solution? [This](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lightning-seeder?path=index.html:25:11) is my remix file.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('json-text-loader', {
  schema: {},
  init: function () {
    var textEntity = document.querySelector('#text');
    var url = 'json/text.json';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( 'GET', url, true );
    request.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

      var jsonGames = JSON.parse( event.target.response )
      textEntity.setAttribute("value", jsonGames.Title)

    } );
    request.send( null );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not manipulate JSON file as you would with an object, because JSON is a string. Thats why we parse them (converting into Javascript object).

From your question I assume that you want to get a random value of key-value pairs, where key is a `Title`. In that case, first you parse JSON response (as you do already - `var jsonGames = JSON.parse( event.target.response )`). So now you have your Javascript object to work with - `jsonGames` and all what is left is to get that random key of it. To do that you can, for ex:

```
var jsonGames = JSON.parse( event.target.response )
var keys = Object.keys(jsonGames);
var random = jsonGames[keys[keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
textEntity.setAttribute("value", random.Title)
```

Please comment if something is not right.

Comment: You are such a star... it worked. I can't believe how helpful the people here are. Seeing as though you seem very knowledgeable could you give me the snippet of code that will return an extra corresponding key value alongside the title? In this case its an image URL attached to the random "Title" you spawned. Working example - https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lightning-seeder?path=json/text.json:5:35

Comment: I've got some code that makes it work but having a hard time merging it with that wonderful 'Random' variable you wrote.  [you can check it here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lightning-seeder?path=index.html:26:0)

Comment: I might misunderstood you, but I guess you overthink it. `keys.length * Math.random() << 0` simply provides a random number in specific range (random index of you array). So you should easily get any other value, like - `random.URL`

Comment: Ok cool, I got it working. Going to edit the original question to reflect the changes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great! If my answer solved your issue, please accept it